# Is there a term that means temporary base camp?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

It seems like there should be a concise term meaning a temporary base of operations. The implication would be that it's where someone has established a transient headquarters in an area they do not intend to be long-term. Scientists may have a dig site, soldiers a temporary command center, a business traveler a hotel, explorers a base camp. What is a generic phrase for this? I'm assuming there's something more concise than "temporary base camp."

Comment: Can't think of a single word, so just commenting: the term ***makeshift camp*** comes to mind.

Comment: *encampment* ?  (a group of tents or temporary shelters put in one place - [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/encampment))

Comment: Base Camp is a well established phrase, as you know. Advance Base Camp is also well established.  I can't think of anything much more concise than Temporary Base Camp, but Interim Base Camp has one less syllable and 2 fewer letters.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's more of a camp or a shelter than a headquarters, you could use **bivouac**.

> [bivouac](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bivouac) (n) - A temporary camp without tents or cover, used especially by soldiers or mountaineers.

Comment: Your answer gives an example of a specific kind of temporary camp, but the questioner is asking for a generic descriptor that covers all temporary bases of operations.